# Arabic text passed as question marks to backend

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net mvc app where target language used is arabic, I have a case where typing arabic in IE browser will be stored as ???? (question marks) in db although db field is in nvarchar.

The case only happens in IE 11 browser, while chrome and other browsers this behavior cannot be produced, it works as expected.

So not sure where exactly to look to figure out this issue or what is causing it ??

Comment: Have you tried adding N before the text in insert query, like N'arabic text to insert'

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we were doing POST through Ajax passing the text as a query string, and we fixed it to be in a body it worked.

This image show little code but to summarize it, the http helper method use model parameter in the body unlike the left side where it was passed as query string

[image]